# DevDemon Forms Mailchimp

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-forms, mailchimp

I'm using DevDemon Forms module and want to map entries to MailChimp.  I inserted my API key into the Settings panel and have added a Subscribe to Mailing field type in form.  But there are no available options within mailing services to choose from -- where I would expect to see my Mailchimp account lists.

Any advice?

Thanks,

Colin

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same procedure and it will populate the list you have in Mailchimp. I had only one list and it worked fine. I'm guessing here that the API Key is linked with the name of that only list. I'm not sure what happens with two lists...

Comment: I didn't figure out the 'right' way -- but I modified the config file to include the API key by default.   That kicked things into place.  But I'm griping over inability to map fields.  From everything I've seen, it's limited to e-mail only.  Womp womp.